# Which int variable was the one who took the last positive value of another int variable...

Tags: c#

The title is confusing, sorry about that. I'm having a go at the "Match Game" (21 matches in a stack, each player takes 1,2, or 3 matches, person who takes the last match is the loser) the only problem I have is figuring out who(which variable) took the last match.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, I'm trying to learn from it so try not to give just code unless it's marked as a spoiler. Thank's guys!

(I'm not sure if there is a function to mark something as a spoiler on this site but if there is I would also appreciate it if someone showed the correct way of doing it and not the strange way I'm using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a separate variable which keeps the number of the current player. When the next player starts his turn, you simply change this variable.